# Interface including an array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "title": "potatoes",
      "category": "Fruit & Veg"
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "title": "custard",
      "category": "Other"
    }
  ]
}
```

...and the following interface:

```
export interface ShoppingItems {
  category: string;
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

When I import the JSON it works but I am rightly warned that `Property 'items' does not exist on type 'ShoppingItems[]'`.

Can I take account of the existence of the items array in the interface or does it need to be accounted for outside of the interface?

Comment: Please add the code with the error message. Your JSON isn't a `ShoppingItems[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce child interface for a single item

```
interface ShoppingItem {
  category: string;
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

export interface ShoppingItems {
   items: ShoppingItem[];
}
```

Comment: many thanks for that. I was guessing it would be something like that but could not get the syntax right.